# Can replicated commands be forced to follow each other in transactional replication?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-administration, transactional-replication

We have transactional replication setup between an SQL Server 2012 box and a SQL Server 2016 box.

Every half an hour the source table articles are altered by `DELETE` then `INSERT` sequence. This sequence comes from a stored procedure executed by an SSIS packgage. Sometimes the `DELETE` has been replicated to the subscriber, but the `INSERT` hasn't made it there yet.

The result is interim missing data at the subscriber. This interim state can last several minutes as the commands get replicated out to all the articles under replication. These table articles are used as the basis for SSRS reports at the subscriber, which become inaccurate due to this issue.

Inside the stored procedures that house the `DELETE - INSERT` statements we tried wrapping both commands in `BEGIN TRAN` - `COMMIT TRAN`, but this didn't appear to help.

Ideally the delete - insert would be combined to happen at once (kind of like `MERGE`) using a different SQL command, or wrapping the commands in something akin to `BEGIN TRAN` - `COMMIT TRAN`